# Android - Share (startActivity) Does Not Work On 7.0

Tags: android, share, unity-game-engine

I am making an app that you can share .mp3 on whatsapp directly with a button inside the app. Share button works properly on Android 6.0 and the versions below. But on Android 7.0 or 7.1.1, share doesn't work at all. Does anybody know why this activity is not doing anything on the new version?

Here is the share function I have

```
        public void sendProccess(string filePath, AudioClip clip)
{
    filePath = Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + clip.name + ".mp3";

        //instantiate the class Intent
        AndroidJavaClass intentClass = new AndroidJavaClass("android.content.Intent");
        AndroidJavaObject intentObject = new AndroidJavaObject("android.content.Intent");
        intentObject.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("setAction", intentClass.GetStatic<string>("ACTION_SEND"));

        //instantiate the class Uri
        AndroidJavaClass uriClass = new AndroidJavaClass("android.net.Uri");
        AndroidJavaObject uriObject = uriClass.CallStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("parse", "file://" + filePath);

        //call putExtra with the uri object of the file
        intentObject.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("putExtra", intentClass.GetStatic<string>("EXTRA_STREAM"), uriObject);
        intentObject.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("setType", "audio/mp3");

        //instantiate the class UnityPlayer
        AndroidJavaClass unity = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");

        //instantiate the object currentActivity
        AndroidJavaObject currentActivity = unity.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");

        //call the activity with our Intent
        currentActivity.Call("startActivity", intentObject);
    }
```

Comment: What happens when you run your app?

Comment: You cannot use `file` `Uri` values on Android 7.0+: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38200282/android-os-fileuriexposedexception-file-storage-emulated-0-test-txt-exposed

Comment: Nothing happens. No error, no catch.

Comment: And since I am doing this on unity c#, I don't know how to implement this steps to it.